# C program to display negative numbers through decimal, octal and hexa-decimal values

Tags: c, numbers, number-systems

```
**Allocation and Storage part of C programming **
```

> I have come with some doubt while trying to print negative numbers through different number system.
>   while printing negative numbers, I am getting different output values.But I am not understanding clearly. If anybody help me will be appreciative.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    int main( )
    {
       char a = -5;
       unsigned char b = -5;
       int c = -5;
       unsigned int d = -5;

      //try to print as using "%d" format specifier to display decimal value
      printf("%d %d",a,b);
      printf("%d %d",c,d);

      //try to print as using "%o" format specifier to display octal value
      printf("%o %o",a,b);
      printf("%o %o",c,d);

      //try to print as using "%x" format specifier to display hexa-decimal value
      printf("%x %x",a,b);
      printf("%x %x",c,d);

      return 0;
}
```

Output:-

```
displaying decimal value 
a = -5 b = 251
c = -5 d = -5

displaying octal value
a = 37777777773 b = 373
c = 37777777773 d = 37777777773

displaying Hexa-decimal value
a = fffffffb  b = fb
c = fffffffb  d = fffffffb
```

Now, come to the point. I don't know why unsigned char would take only 8 bits(1 Byte) and other gets allocated to 32 bits (4 Bytes).

Answer (score 1):

When a `char` value is passed to `printf`, it is promoted to `int`. `printf` is printing this `int` value.

When the `char` value is −5 and it is promoted to `int`, the `int` value is −5. For a 32-bit two’s complement `int`, −5 is represented with the bits fffffffb<sub>16</sub>. So, when you ask `printf` to format that with `%x`, you can “fffffffb”. (Technically, `%x` is for an `unsigned int`, and passing an `int` does not match, but most C implementations will accept it.) **The eight-bit `char` was promoted to a 32-bit `int`, and that is why you see 32-bit results.**

You can tell `printf` that the value it receives originated as a character value by using `%hho` or `%hhx` instead of `%o` or `%x`, and it may adjust accordingly. (Again, the `o` and `x` specifiers are for `unsigned int` values, and passing an `int` does not match, but it may work.) A pedantically correct solution is to use `(unsigned int) (unsigned char) x` when passing a signed `char` `x` for a  `%o` or `%x` conversion.

Comment: Mr.Eric  if you notice the answer for unsigned char, it will give up to the range of unsigned char(0-255) for every format specifier %d - 251, %o - 373, %x - fb  but others are gives 32 bits range

Comment: @MKTharma: The eight-bit `char` is promoted to a 32-bit `int`. When the `char` value is positive, the high bits of the 32-bit `int` are zeros, and you do not see them. When the `char` value is negative, the high bits of the 32-bit `int` are ones, and you see them. I added a paragraph about this.

Comment: like wise from your concerned about negative values,the highest bits of the 32-bit int are ones, But happened while unsigned char of every printf function in above my program. If you notice my program, There I initialize unsigned char b = -5; and It's negative value why it cannot bit up to 32-bit for unsigned char b;

Comment: @MKTharma: `unsigned char` objects never have negative values. When you assign −5 to an eight-bit `unsigned char`, it is converted to 251 (256−5). When you print an `unsigned char` with value 251, it is promoted to an `int` with value 251, and the high bits are zeros.